# Remove certain empty spaces in a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, replace

I have a string as following:

```
strMyString = "4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin    -$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC    -$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC   ";
```

I want to remove empty spaces after the name.

I tried using

```
string.Replace(" ", string.Empty)
```

But this will remove all the empty spaces in the string, I wanted to remove only empty spaces after the name part.

My final output should like this

```
strMyString = "4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin-$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC-$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC";
```

The space in between the names should be intact.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem can't be solved as is. What is a *name* in the context of your string and how would it be identified as such? Would removing spaces preceding a `-` be a valid option? Because that is solvable, the former isn't unless you provide more information about the structure of your data.

Comment: Ok..Removing spaces preceding -$@%@$ should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    string strMyString = "4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin    -$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC    -$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC   ";
    string pattern = "\\s+-";
    string replacement = "-";
    string result = Regex.Replace(strMyString, pattern, replacement);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/luJHd3

Answer (score 0):

Following your comments the following should do:

```
var newText = string.Join("-$@%@$", text.Split(new[] {"-$@%@$"}, 
                                               StringSplitOptions.None)
                                        .Select(t => t.TrimEnd()));
```

Comment: Split gives an error: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: @Santosh Yeah sorry, forgot the exact overload, typing on a phone here ;)

Comment: After you edit: Now Split cannot convert from string to char

Comment: @Santosh Changed the code before your last commentary and it should work just fine. Not sure what error you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string strMyString = "4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin    -$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC    -$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC   ";
        var subStrings = strMyString.Split('-').ToList();
        var newSubstrings = new List<string>();
        subStrings.ForEach(substring => newSubstrings.Add(substring.Trim(' ')));
        var newString = string.Join("-",newSubstrings);
        Console.WriteLine(newString);
```

Comment: @user326608 do keep in mind though that this will also add spaces if a name contains -, e.g. "jean-philippe" would result into "jean - philippe"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the pattern is a set of number/name pair, internally separated by "-|@$@|-", with the pairs separated by "-$@%@$-", this seems to work:

```
 string input =
     "4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin    -$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC    -$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC   ";
 const string separator = "-$@%@$-";
 const string pattern = @"\s+-\$@%@\$-";
 var regex= new Regex(pattern);
 var firstPass = regex.Replace(input, separator);
 var result = firstPass.TrimEnd(' ');
```

After running, `result` looks like:

```
"4654564-|@$@|-Jennifer Austin-$@%@$-646565546-|@$@|-Dutchin Henry LLC-$@%@$-444309386-|@$@|-Winston Cooper LLC"
```

The Regex keys off the separator between the pairs, removing any spaces before the separator.  Then, the trailing spaces are still there, so I remove that with `TrimEnd`

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and easiest to understand solution that I can think of is this:

```
strMyString = strMyString.Replace(@"    -$@%@$", @"-$@%@$").TrimEnd(' ');
```

As it has been pointed out, if there are varying amounts of whitespaces, this will not work and this would be a better solution:

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);
strMyString = regex.Replace(strMyString, "");
```

Comment: Yes. Your solution is valid only for a certain amount of whitespaces. If there are less it won’t do anything, if there are more it won’t remove all of them.

Comment: @InBetween, for or the provided input there is always a consistent number of whitespaces. This is a valid solution. Even still, see additional solution that could be used in the case of varying amounts of whitespaces.

Comment: Now if there are consecutive whitespaces anywhere in the string they will be all replaced, that isn't the requirement either. I didn't downvote but I'm fairly sure why your answer did get a -1; your solution is very specific and assumes something the OP never said. All other answers are either dead wrong or consider a variable number of whitespaces.

Comment: I took the only input that was given and provided a solution to produce the desired output. We kind of have to assume that the input always follows the same format since that is the only format we were given. What happens to our solutions if the substring `-$@%@$` occurs after any whitespace that _isn't_ succeeding a name?

Comment: I don't care, the OP has explicitly said that removing all whitespaces prior to `-$@%@$` is a valid approach. You are assuming things, the other answers that are correct don't. Really, its not worth discussing anymore.